# Win 8.1 Light dismiss popup closing on sizedchanged/orientation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, popup, windows-8.1

I have a couple of popups that all use the light dismiss feature. When the popup is open, and the user then rotates the device, or resizes the screen, then the light dismiss is activated, closing the popup.

Is this the default windows behaviour? Is it possible to keep the popup open for size changes/rotation, or would this be going against guidelines.